# Cors origin React Api plateform

Tags: reactjs, symfony, api-platform.com

I have a REST API with symfony/api-plateform on port 8000 and front app React on port 3000

In my React App: I want to get file with url

```
let url = 'http://localhost:8000/delivrables/school/2021/b1_cpd/homework_matiere_0__devoir_0/picard-%C3%89lisabeth.zip'

axios.get(url)
    .then(res => {
       console.log(res)
     })
```

but I get a CORS error :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/delivrables/school/2021/b1_cpd/homework_matiere_0__devoir_0/picard-%C3%89lisabeth.zip' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
react_devtools_backend.js:4049
```

I have configurated my app symfony/api-plateform for cors :

```
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=^https?://.*?$
```

When I call this URL (for exemple) with postman (http://localhost:8000/delivrables/school/2021/b1_cpd/homework_matiere_0__devoir_0/picard-%C3%89lisabeth.zip) that work.

Try with header (not work) :

```
axios(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
}
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response)
})
```

nelmio_cors.yml

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        origin_regex: true
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
        expose_headers: ['Link']
        max_age: 3600
        hosts: []
    paths:
        '^/':
            origin_regex: true
            allow_origin: ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
            allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
            allow_headers: ['X-Custom-Auth']
            max_age: 3600
            hosts: ['^api\.']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this to your React project's **package.json**

```
 "proxy": "http://localhost:8000"
```

But of course this will work just for this dev server setup, not for production.

And also in this case you should use "relative" url in your request, that is starting with `/delivrables`...

Comment: Thx, That work but that don't work for production :/

Comment: For production use you'll need to setup CORS on the server.

Comment: You've already tried to do that, so what might help is to look at the HTTP headers sent by your server in the browser dev tools **Network** tab.